# Duplicate Value Found: <unknown> Duplicates Value on Record With Id: <unknown>

Tags: custom-controller

I am getting this problem while saving the following controller class class

```
public class NewAndExistingController 
{
    public Account account { get; private set; }

    public NewAndExistingController() 
    {
        Id id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        account = (id == null) ? new Account() : [SELECT Name, Phone, Industry FROM Account WHERE Id =:id];
    }
    public PageReference save() 
    {
        try 
        {
            upsert(account);
        } 
        catch(System.DMLException e) 
        {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            return null;
        }
        // After Save, navigate to the default view page:
        return (new ApexPages.StandardController(account)).view();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any unique fields on the Account object?

Comment: @Bachovski The error he is getting is on Save of code not when code is executed .Pls see answer below which i suspect is cause

Comment: @Irfan when i have same code paste in my org there is no error it saved without error.

Answer (score 1):

I see this as a simple syntax issue

CHange the code below

```
Id id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
```

to shown below

```
id recId  = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        account = (recId   == null) ? new Account() : [SELECT Name, Phone, Industry FROM Account WHERE Id =:recId  ];
```

You have kept variable name and datatype Id as same ,hence the issue .

Comment: That's the next thing I was going to suggest :)

Comment: same error is showing, if i change the code from the above code

Comment: can anybody help in this

Comment: @IrfanPasha Delete the old class and make a new one .Dont see any issue in apex classes